# sim800 cme erro2 when i pass at commands through code arduino esp32

Tags: c++, arduino, gsm, sim800

I am trying to push sensor data to aws cloud database through sim800 gsm module.

I am able to do it by entering the at commands manually via serial monitor but when i incorporate the at commands in the code to automate the process so I don't have to enter commands manually I am getting cme error 3.

Please guide how to solve or identify the problem.

**Code**

```
#include <Arduino.h> //Arduino librabry...optional
#include <SPI.h>//SPI communication library
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>//library with GSM commands

HardwareSerial SerialGSM(1);

TinyGsm modemGSM(SerialGSM);

const int BAUD_RATE = 115200;


//Pin definition for RX and TX GPIO2 and GPIO4 are the pins in ESP32 Wroom
const int RX_PIN = 4, TX_PIN = 2;
//const char *APN = "";
//const char *USER = "";
//const char *PASSWORD = "";


//Initialize the gsm
void setupGSM() {
  SerialGSM.begin(BAUD_RATE, SERIAL_8N1, RX_PIN, TX_PIN, false);
  delay(3000);
  Serial.println(modemGSM.getModemInfo());
delay(1000);
}


String sendAT(String command)
{
  String response = "";
  SerialGSM.println(command);
  // aguardamos até que haja resposta do SIM800L
  while(!SerialGSM.available());

  response = SerialGSM.readString();
  Serial.println(response);
  return response;  
}



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
  Serial.println("Starting the device");
  Serial.println("Initializing GSM device");
  setupGSM();
delay(5000);
SerialGSM.println("AT+CMEE=1");


}
unsigned long start;
void loop() {

//SerialGSM.println("AT+CMEE?");
sendAT("AT+CMEE?");
 // SerialGSM.write("AT+COPS?\r\n");
   delay(100);
    //SerialGSM.println("AT+CSQ");
    sendAT("AT+CSQ");
//     if(SerialGSM.available()){
//       Serial.write(SerialGSM.read());       
//    }
    delay(100);

    // SerialGSM.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");
     sendAT("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");
    delay(1000);

    
    // SerialGSM.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"www\"");
     sendAT("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"www\"");
    delay(1000);
    
   //SerialGSM.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
   sendAT("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
     delay(2000);
    //SerialGSM.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
    sendAT("AT+HTTPINIT");
  delay(1000);
   //SerialGSM.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
   sendAT("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
   delay(1000);

   //SerialGSM.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://ec2-18-217-119-145.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/?light=0&var=1&var2=2&var3=3&var4=4\"");
   sendAT("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://ec2-18-217-119-145.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/?light=0&var=1&var2=2&var3=3&var4=4\"");
   delay(1000);

   //SerialGSM.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
   sendAT("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
   
   delay(2000);  
   //start=millis();
// 
//  while(millis()-start<1000)
//  {
//    if(SerialGSM.available()){
//         Serial.write(SerialGSM.read());
//                             }
//  }    
 }
```

Comment: When you write you get "error 3" you mean `+CME ERROR: 3` (meaning "operation not allowed")? If yes, what command does specifically raise that error?

Comment: yes when i enter at +sapbr command